# Nelson-Oppen: Does 'quantifier-free' mean that is decidable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, decidability, quantifier-elimination

Given two theories $T_1$ and $T_2$ with disjoint-signatures
$Σ_1$ and $Σ_2$ respectively, and a conjunction of literals $φ$ over
$Σ_1 \cup Σ_2$, we want to decide if $φ$ is satisfiable under $T1∪T2$. Nelson and Oppen [*G. Nelson and D. C. Oppen. Simplification by cooperating decision procedures*] provided a method for combining the satisfiability procedures for $T_1$ and $T_2$ to produce a satisfiability procedure for $T_1 \cup T_2$.

However, Nelson-Oppen is: *solely applicable to (disjoint-signature) quantifier-free theories*. Thus, are we referring to those theories that admit quantifier elimination (i.e., they does this mean decidable)?

I ask because 'quantifier-free' sounds to me like quantifiers will not be accepted in the signature.

Comment: (1) What is Nelson-Oppen? Please give a reference to a precise statement. (2) I would interpret "quantifier-free theory" to mean a theory whose axioms have no quantifiers. This is quite different from "theory admitting quantifier elimination", which means that *modulo the axioms* (which might have arbitrary quantifier complexity), every *other* formula is equivalent to one with no quantifiers. Finally, the notion of decidability is different from both of these notions. Not all decidable theories admit quantifier elimination, and not all theories admitting quantifier elimination are decidable.

Comment: Thank! I will clarify what Nelson-Oppen is. Also, I did not know that: can I know an example of a decidable theory that does not admit quantifier elimination? And a theory that does admit elimination but is not decidable?

Comment: Any recursively axiomatized complete theory is decidable, but not all have QE. For example, the theory of real closed fields in the language of fields (the formula $\exists y\,y^2=x$ is not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula) or the complete theory of the structure $(\mathbb{N},S)$ (the formula $\exists y\,S(y)=x$ is not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula).

Comment: On the other hand, QE is often used to show decidability - but what it actually does is to reduce the decision problem to the decision problem for quantifier-free sentences. This only helps if the quantifier-free consequences of the theory are decidable. In fact, you can take any theory and force it to have QE by a process called Morleyization - without affecting decidability. For example, take PA and add a new $n$-ary relation symbol $P_\varphi$ for each formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and a new axiom $\forall x_1\dots x_n(\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)\leftrightarrow P_\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n))$.

Comment: This expansion of PA rather trivially has QE (every formula $\varphi$ is equivalent to an atomic formula $P_\varphi$!) but it's a recursive extension of PA, so it is undecidable.

Comment: But the theory of real closed fields does accept quantifier eliminations, does not it? I mean, the  Tarski-Seidenberg theorem is not precisely that? On the other side, I will research Morleyization. Seems like a really interesting path for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: RCF admits QE in the language of *ordered* fields. Without the ordering in the language, it does not.